# Newton-Raphson converges with rate higher than 2?

Tags: numerical-methods, newton-raphson, numerical-calculus

Can we find an example of a function $f$ such that Newton-Raphson converges with rate higher than 2?

Comment: Sure, easily. Try to find the root of $f(x)=\sin x=0$ with starting value $x_0=3$. It converges cubically, because $f''(x_\infty)=0$ ($x_\infty=\pi$, naturally).

Comment: Even faster: Let $f$ be a non-constant linear function. Newton-Raphson will give you the exact root on the first iteration.